# Should the RabbitMQ consumer be part of a microservice web app (e.g. FastApi) or a separate Python script?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, microservices, fastapi

I am studying microservice architecture and currently working on a pet project to test my knowledge. I am trying to determine the best approach for adding a RabbitMQ consumer to a microservice-based application.

For example, I have two services, "reviews" and "movies". Both microservices are FastAPI applications. When a new review is created, a RabbitMQ message is sent to the "movies" service to recalculate the movie's average rating. Should the RabbitMQ consumer be part of the "movies" microservice or a separate Python script?

Additionally, I would appreciate any article recommendations on this topic.

Comment: The one that owns the information.

Answer (score 1):

This question seams to be a [duplicate of "Should I separate RabbitMQ consumer from the rest of the code?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58224091/should-i-separate-rabbitmq-consumer-from-the-rest-of-the-code?rq=2).

So let me explain a little background to you to understand the basics, FOA try to understand why you need RabbitMQ, the concept lies in understading the usage of [Queues or Message Brokers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker). This is only required in [asynchronous communication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/asynchronous-message-based-communication), when the client is not ready to accept your message and you have to store the messages in some Queue for some temporary purpose.

This is the purpose for which you have your RabbitMQ is available; so better to have it separate as this is a separate service; which many of your other services may use as a middle man to communicate or exchange their messages.
Moreover the microservices' approach is to have separate services to have [Loose coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling).